# Reading sensors data from the sysfs interface (hwmon) occasionally results in a blocking call (longer execution time for the function than expected)

Tags: c++, file-io, blocking, nonblocking, file-descriptor

I have an ARM machine that runs Linux (BusyBox). I need to frequently read the data in this file `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input` which contains voltage. It's located in the virtual file system `sysfs` under the `/sys/class/hwmon/` directory.

The file contains data that looks like this (SSHed to the device).

```
root:~# cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input
10345
root:~# cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input
10250
```

Usually reading the data from that file takes about `1 ms` but there are occasions where it takes about `1 sec`. Unfortunately for me, I'm not able to replicate this issue on my bench since it doesn't happen very frequently on the field.

I have checked the CPU utilization and it's usually less than `60%` when this issue occurs. I'm not sure why occasionally reading from that file results in what appears to be a blocking call that results in a longer execution time for the function.

I'm not sure if I'm dealing with a bigger problem that's occurring on the virtual file system `sysfs` or if the code I have in `readVoltage()` isn't completely non-blocking.

Here is a snippet of that code that I had to tweak

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

uint64_t GetClockCount(void);
float calculateLoopTime(uint32_t tUsec1, uint32_t tUsec2);

void readVoltage()
{

    static const char VoltageFile[] = "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input";
    static int VoltageFD = -1;

    if (-1 == VoltageFD)
    {
        VoltageFD = open(VoltageFile, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    }

        if (-1 == VoltageFD)
        {
            std::cout << "couldn't open FD for " << VoltageFile << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            static const size_t bufSize = 15;
            char buffer[bufSize];

            fd_set input;
            FD_ZERO(&input);
            FD_SET(VoltageFD, &input);

            struct timeval to;
            to.tv_sec = 0;
            to.tv_usec = 0;
            int n = 0;
            n = select(VoltageFD + 1, &input, NULL, NULL, &to);

            if (n > 0)
            {
                ssize_t bytes_read = pread(VoltageFD, buffer, bufSize, 0);

                if (bytes_read > 0)
                {
                    float voltage = (atof(buffer) / 1000.0f);

                    std::cout << "voltage= " << voltage << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }


int main()
{
    uint32_t start_time = GetClockCount();
    
    readVoltage();
    
    uint32_t end_time = GetClockCount();
    
    float time_diff = calculateLoopTime(start_time, end_time);
    
    std::cout << "function took " << time_diff << " ms to execute" << std::endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}

uint64_t GetClockCount(void)
{
    struct timespec now;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now))
        return 0;
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(now.tv_sec) * 1000000 + now.tv_nsec / 1000;
}


float calculateLoopTime(uint32_t tUsec1, uint32_t tUsec2)
{
    float time_diff = 0;

    if (tUsec1 != tUsec2)
    {
        uint32_t time_diff_temp = 0;

        if (tUsec2 > tUsec1)
        {
            time_diff_temp = (tUsec2 - tUsec1);
        }
    
        // Scale from microseconds to milliseconds
        time_diff = static_cast<float>(time_diff_temp) / 1000;
    }

    return time_diff;
}
```

You can run the code here but obviously you won't get the the voltage since this file `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input` doesn't exist on that online IDE.

https://onlinegdb.com/d0wcJ0tzT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote in the `readVoltage()` is non-blocking. You can use the fact, that `read()` on non-blocking descriptor would return E_AGAIN / E_WOULDBLOCK errno if reading would block and therefore remove lines with `select()` and setting FD_SET (less code).

You can't be sure what is happening between `GetClockCount()` calls. If your system is under load (like you say less 60%) it can be doing something else. Hardware thread can be doing some other operation even if it's not doing it 100% time it can introduce some jitter when switching back to your sysfs reading code.

To be more accurate try to measure only `pread()` invocation time but therefore still be possibility for running some other process' code, especially when talking about system under load.

You can also try to use `perf` to check out what's going on in your program. Look [here](https://canvas.kth.se/courses/24933/pages/tutorial-introduction-to-timing-gperftools-perf-and-papi) to check out that perf can show how many context-switches occured during running your program.

Try to also measure calling plain sysfs reading by using:

```
root:~# cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input
```

All the results should show that something other is done by the system and `pread()` call is not blocking itself as it's double checked - once using non-blocking flag and secondary when checking if `select()` returned ready descriptor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @asmie. Regarding the `perf` tool, I don't have it installed on the busy box and it's not easy for me to update that device at this moment. If there are other tools to use let me know. However, I'm planning as you suggested to measure only the `pread()` invocation time. Also, I will check for errors after that function is called since I don't currently do that. In addition, I'm planning to upload the `/tmp/dmesg.log` to the server to review, let me know if there are other logs worth looking into in case there is a kernel/file system issue.

Comment: I will also create a function that reads the led brightness from this interface `/sys/class/leds` as frequent as the voltage from this interface `/sys/class/hwmon`. If we run into the same issue in both functions around the same timestamp then maybe we are dealing with some systemic issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reporting back the results. Per my last test, I learned that the `pread()` is what is causing the excessive loop time (blocking). The `pread()` returned -1, which is an indicator of an error. I checked `errno` and got error code 110, which says **"Connection timed out"**. Two things, first, I'm not understanding why the connection timed out at some point. Second, in the case when it times out, how can I prevent the `pread()` function from blocking, which according to my test results, that function took ~990 ms to execute.

Comment: Also, reading the led brightness from this interface `/sys/class/leds` as frequent as the voltage from this interface `/sys/class/hwmon` did not have the issue. This seems to be specific to `/sys/class/hwmon` interface.