# pread() caused a blocking call due to error code 110 "Connection timed out"

Tags: c++, kernel, blocking, nonblocking, file-descriptor

I have an ARM machine that runs Linux (BusyBox). I need to frequently read the data in this file `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input` which contains voltage. It's located in the virtual file system `sysfs` under the `/sys/class/hwmon/` directory.

Usually reading the data from that file takes about `1 ms` but there are occasions where it takes about `1 sec`. I root caused it and noticed the blocking call is invoked when `pread()` returns an error saying that the connection has timed out.

First of all, I'm using `select()` which told me the file descriptor has data available to be read without blocking.

> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file
> descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become
> "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). A file
> descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the
> corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.

Even the FD was opened in `O_NONBLOCK`.

`VoltageFD = open(VoltageFile, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`

So I don't understand why `select()` told me there is data available but as soon as I called `pread()`, it resulted in `~990 ms` of blocking call due to the connection timing out. I'm not even sure what that means since I'm not doing any sockets.

**Questions:**

1. **What are some possible reasons that caused the connection to time out?**
2. **How can I prevent `pread()` from blocking? (main goal)**

**Demo of the code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

uint64_t GetClockCount(void);
float calculateLoopTime(uint32_t tUsec1, uint32_t tUsec2);

void readVoltage()
{

    static const char VoltageFile[] = "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input";
    static int VoltageFD = -1;

    if (-1 == VoltageFD)
    {
        VoltageFD = open(VoltageFile, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    }

        if (-1 == VoltageFD)
        {
            std::cout << "couldn't open FD for " << VoltageFile << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            static const size_t bufSize = 15;
            char buffer[bufSize];

            fd_set input;
            FD_ZERO(&input);
            FD_SET(VoltageFD, &input);

            struct timeval to;
            to.tv_sec = 0;
            to.tv_usec = 0;
            int n = 0;
            n = select(VoltageFD + 1, &input, NULL, NULL, &to);

            if (n > 0)
            {
                ssize_t bytes_read = pread(VoltageFD, buffer, bufSize, 0);

                if (bytes_read > 0)
                {
                    float voltage = (atof(buffer) / 1000.0f);

                    std::cout << "voltage= " << voltage << std::endl;
                }
                
                if (-1 == bytes_read)
                {
                    int localErrno = errno;
                    std::cout <<"pread() returned error code " << localErrno << 
                    " meaning " << strerror(localErrno) << std::endl;
                                                          
                }
            }
            
            if (-1 == n)
            {
                int localErrno = errno;
                   
                std::cout <<"select() returned error code " << localErrno << 
                    " meaning " << strerror(localErrno) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }


int main()
{
    uint32_t start_time = GetClockCount();
    
    readVoltage();
    
    uint32_t end_time = GetClockCount();
    
    float time_diff = calculateLoopTime(start_time, end_time);
    
    std::cout << "function took " << time_diff << " ms to execute" << std::endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}

uint64_t GetClockCount(void)
{
    struct timespec now;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now))
        return 0;
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(now.tv_sec) * 1000000 + now.tv_nsec / 1000;
}


float calculateLoopTime(uint32_t tUsec1, uint32_t tUsec2)
{
    float time_diff = 0;

    if (tUsec1 != tUsec2)
    {
        uint32_t time_diff_temp = 0;

        if (tUsec2 > tUsec1)
        {
            time_diff_temp = (tUsec2 - tUsec1);
        }
    
        // Scale from microseconds to milliseconds
        time_diff = static_cast<float>(time_diff_temp) / 1000;
    }

    return time_diff;
}
```

You can run the code here but obviously you won't get the voltage since this file `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in7_input` doesn't exist on that online IDE.

https://onlinegdb.com/17Lt92G4s

Comment: "I root caused it and noticed the blocking call is invoked" - Not sure how did you "notice" a **blocking call**. The term "blocking call" is not about large time required to perform a request. This term is about "the data is ready", but no one guarantee that *receiving* that data will be fast. When a blocking call is required to obtain a data, then `read` in `O_NONBLOCK` mode would return EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. Returning ETIMEDOUT means **some other** problem, which is most likely specific to the given device (hmon sensors).

Comment: BTW, you already have been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72771169/3440745) several months ago that there is no "blocking" semantic in your problem. Why do you ask again about that?

Comment: Your right, it's not a blocking call per say, I just perceived as is and treated it as something undesirable since I'm running a time critical application. I created this question since I learned more about the issue and had follow up questions. I accepted the other answer. What options do I have regarding the ETIMEDOUT issue? I know I can start a thread but is there anything else I can do to handle when reading from that file takes longer than expected?  I have seen it take in some rare occasions take up to 10 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I wanted to clarify when the *pread()* took longer than expected to execute, it actually didn't read that file successfully, rather it returned an error "**Connection timed out**". So in reality, there was no data ready/available even though *select()* indicated so.

Comment: "there was no data ready/available even though `select()` indicated so" - Actually, in general `select()` indicates that the data can be read (or write) **without blocking**. But meaning of "blocking" is not defined in general and it is specific for devices. **Normally**, ability to read without blocking means that "the data is ready", as I described in my first comment. But `select` also returns in case when reading from the file **would return an error**, if that error is not caused by blocking reasons. Since reading the file returns `ETIMEDOUT`, `select` is perfectly allowed to return.

Comment: Generally, the **sequence** of `select` and `read`ing from the file, opened **with** `O_NONBLOCK` flag, is the **same** as `read`ing from the file, opened **without** `O_NONBLOCK`. So, unless you want to `select` from several files, or with a timeout, it is simpler to not use `select` at all.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, so what other options do I have to handle this issue better? Ultimately, I want to avoid those occasional scenarios when `pread()` takes longer than expected to execute, in my case due to the "**Connection timed out**" error. I would think there has to be some other ways to handle this better.

Comment: I don't know how to handle you issue. The only thing I am sure: the issue is absolutely not related to *blocking*. The same assurance has been given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72771169/3440745) to your previous question.